# Why does windows ask for the (existing) password twice?

Tags: windows, passwords, credentials

When I specify an account for an application pool to run under, in IIS, I am asked to supply the password twice:

[image]

I don't understand the purpose of 'confirming' the password for an existing account. Sure, if you're setting up a new account it is a good idea to ask for the password twice, but this seems superfluous for an existing account.

1. Is there a way to disable this, and get it to only ask once?
2. Is there a useful purpose, in asking for the password twice?

I also remember the wireless connection dialog, in I think XP, asking for the password twice, which always confused me!

Comment: At that place they probably ask twice to make sure the password is right. Because if it wasn't right, you wouldn't get an immediate feedback about it. Instead some service would fail and you would only know about the details by checking your event log. That's what I assume anyway.

Comment: It does check your credentials on hitting 'OK', so you do get immediate feedback on if the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is for the case where you mistype your password. Example, if I want to use the password 'password', and there is no confirm password, and my finger slip in the middle of the typing, I could end up with:

```
pssword
pzssword
paqssword
...
```

By making you type the password twice, you can be sure you typed it right the two time, so it is really the password you want, and not a slighly different one.

(BTW: There is no way to disable this)

Comment: It checks that your credentials are valid as soon as you hit ok, so knows if you've entered the wrong password anyway.

Comment: Isn t that the creation of a new user?

Comment: This process is for specifying existing credentials for an app pool to run under. I did wonder if the form could ALSO be used to create a new user (as the double password field would make sense in that scenario), but it can't.

Comment: Well, in that case I don t know why it would need double password.